# payara 5 behind nginx soap location changin port

Tags: soap, nginx-reverse-proxy, payara

i I have a soap service on payara 5 behind an nginx load balancer configured as follows

```
upstream lb_backend {
  server 192.168.50.20:8080;
  server 192.168.50.20:2080;
}

server {
  listen 192.168.50.1:5080;
  server_name _;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.backend.tracker.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.backend.tracker.log;

  location / {
    #proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_pass http://lb_backend/;
  }
}
```

When a client makes a request, nginx receives it, but the client returns a 404 response. I check the wsdl url via browser I found out that the location tag is different than the nginx server url

I set in the browser http://92.168.50.1:5080/docservice/WSGenDoc

```
<service name="WSGenDoc">
  <port name="WSGenDocPort" binding="tns:WSGenDocPortBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://192.168.50.1:2080/docservice/WSGenDoc"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

If I refresh the port change

```
<service name="WSGenDoc">
  <port name="WSGenDocPort" binding="tns:WSGenDocPortBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://192.168.50.1:8080/docservice/WSGenDoc"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

As you can see the ip is maintained and the port changes but it should be the nginx port (5080)

```
<service name="WSGenDoc">
  <port name="WSGenDocPort" binding="tns:WSGenDocPortBinding">
    <soap:address location="http://192.168.50.1:5080/docservice/WSGenDoc"/>
  </port>
</service>
```

The client is redirected to the url established in the location tag, but on the server 192.160.50.1 there is only the nginx port (5080). I have no idea why port is being changed to 8080 or 2080. According to the nginx documentation, the line `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` allows you to set these values, but only sets the IP defined in the $host variable. The port is the one in the upstream nodes.

Has something similar happened to anyone? I have found many posts but they only refer to changing http to https.

Thank you very much for any help you can give me. Greetings